# Auto run any terminated process on OpenWRT

Tags: openwrt

I have written a program of TCP server running on OpneWRT OS for MedaTek MT7688 module. Using Init Scripts I am starting my program at boot up.
If some how (e.g. segmentation fault) my program get terminated, What is the way to start this program again automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I have wrote a scripts calls monitor.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ 1 ]; do

    PROCESS=`ps | grep myApp | grep -v grep`

    if [ -z "$PROCESS" ]; then
         echo "Process is not running" 
        /root/myApp  2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null &

    fi

    sleep 3
done
exit 0
```

Please comment on this.